# Flink installation question on MacOS Monterey?

Tags: vmd

I want to make a movie using VMD, but when I follow the instructions it can just produce the image frames in the ppm format. I noticed I need to preinstall some packages for VMD to be able to make a movie. I figured that I need to install Flink and it guided me to a browser which requires me to download and install xCode app. It is just taking forever to download the app. I also tried using Quick time maker to make a movie from image frames but it seems it cannot read ppm files. Can anybody help me wit the issue? how can I make a movie from ppm files or how can I make VMD movie maker work without using xCode?

Than you so much

Comment: I’m not sure what “Flink” is. I think you want “ffmpeg” which you can install with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was [answered by Geoff](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9258/flink-installation-question-on-macos-monterey#comment19353_9258).

`ffmpeg` can be installed with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) this [worked](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9258/flink-installation-question-on-macos-monterey#comment19354_9258) for the OP.